# A component for get vibrate effects with color changing

Tags: c#, animation, microsoft-metro

Today I am designing a guitar application in  metro apps. I am needed to create a component for guitar frets.

[image]

Please, does anyone have any idea on how to implement it? 
Thank.

Comment: I think the easiest way to get a vibrate visual effect is to do a directional blur on the strings (direction is perpendicular to the strings), which slowly decreases.

Comment: Thx for response to my question. Please can you provide a example for that..

Comment: Do any one have any idea related to my question. It's better if you can provide me answer that how can i use this in metro apps.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you are asking how to create the vibrate visual effect for the string.

The basic idea is to simulate motion, just like real strings move. Probably the easiest way to achieve this vibrate visual effect is to do create a motion (directional) blur on the strings, with the direction perpendicular to the string.

Here is an example I did using After Effects (animation software):
[image]

In the first case, I used a simple directional blur on the string (rectangle). In the second case, I added a second layer with the same rectangle/string, but a smaller amount of blur, which in my opinion gives a slightly better animation.

Now the obvious problem here is how do you do this in Metro/C#? I am unfamiliar with this framework, so I can't tell you exactly how, but I can tell you 2 methods:

1. AFAIK, metro uses WPF, and WPF has a blur effect which you could use, although I doubt it can be directional. But still, if your strings are simple enough, and the edges are not visible on the screen, it could work just fine.
2. The hard way: generate the blur pixel by pixel. To do this, you need to know that every pixel will blend with the pixels around it. A directional blur will only blend with pixels in that direction, while an ordinary blur will blend with all pixels around it. The radius means how many pixels you blend with.

   Blending means calculating a weighted average between colors (color components), the further you go from the current pixel, the smaller the weight.

   If you want to go this way, these wikipedia articles are good reads: [Box blur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_blur), [Gaussian blur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur), you may find formulas, ideas here.

Comment: Thank you very much Tibi for your valuable ideas.. I will try those options that you have mentioned. Thank you again.